# Run mongo query written as string using python without using any library function (find_one, etc)

Tags: mongodb

I am creating mongo query from my MySql query. So my mongo query is like

```
db.getCollection("SPECIALITY_MASTER").aggregate(
    [{
            "$project" : {
                "_id" : NumberInt(0),
                "SPECIALITY_MASTER" : "$$ROOT"
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "SPECIALITY_MASTER_spec_name" : "$SPECIALITY_MASTER.spec_name"
                },
                "COUNT(SPECIALITY_MASTER_spec_name)" : {
                    "$sum" : NumberInt(1)
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project" : {
                "COUNT" : "$COUNT(SPECIALITY_MASTER_spec_name)",
                "NAME" : "$_id.SPECIALITY_MASTER_spec_name",
                "_id" : NumberInt(0)
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

I am using python for this. Now I need to run same query using python. Tried with pymongo but it has its own function to perform operation. Is it any way i am missing to execute this query exatly through python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python - pymongo specifically implementation is just a tad different, for example like you said `findOne` becomes `find_one` and so on, meaning you're aggregation is fine we just need to adjust it a little to match the correct syntax.

```
connection = pymongo.MongoClient(connection_url)
collection = connection[database_name][collection_name]

result = list(collection.aggregate(
    [{
            "$project" : {
                "_id" : 0,
                "SPECIALITY_MASTER" : "$$ROOT"
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "SPECIALITY_MASTER_spec_name" : "$SPECIALITY_MASTER.spec_name"
                },
                "COUNT(SPECIALITY_MASTER_spec_name)" : {
                    "$sum" : 1
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project" : {
                "COUNT" : "$COUNT(SPECIALITY_MASTER_spec_name)",
                "NAME" : "$_id.SPECIALITY_MASTER_spec_name",
                "_id" : 0
            }
        }
    ]
))
```

You can obviously skip the `list()` part and iterate over the cursor instead.